# the project required a platform SDK (UAP, version 10586.0) that is not installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

i installed VS 2015 With update 2 yesterday and then i Downloaded Windows 10 SDK 1058.0.10586.15,Windows 10 mobile emulator 10.0.10586.11 and universal tools and then i installed them

now if i try to create a new Universal app project, VS show me this error

"the project required a platform SDK (UAP, version 10586.0) that is not installed"

this is a picture of error : [image]

for some reasons i cannot install universal app tools or anything via VS installer when it try to download them

please check out this link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bffa9fb-bd19-4993-bfa3-e0bc8eaf8f45/cannot-download-windows-10-tools-uwp-tools?forum=vssetup

thanks in advance!

Comment: Try repairing the Visual Studio.

Comment: are you mean everything is OK?  and all necessary packages is already  installed ?

Answer (score 1):

Download the newer SDK (10586.212) or wait a few hours until the issue gets fixed. It is a known issue and they should have a hot fix out soon.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in Visual Studia 2015 Update 2. You can fix this by installing the standalone setup of the SDK:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when tried to create a universal app in VS2015. It might be an existing bug with Xamarin.
Try to create a Blank App (Native Shared) instead of (Xamarin.Forms.Shared).Hope that helps.

[image: Creating Universal App]

Answer (score 0):

Verify your version installed in **Control Panel -> Programs > Programs and features.**

Then try to change the `UWP.csproject` file manually for the correct version.

[image: notepad++ with UWP.csproject opened]